# Alfresco custom role (permission) is not working as expected with 5.2.0

Tags: permissions, alfresco, alfresco-share, user-roles, alfresco-enterprise

I am using `alfresco-content-services 5.2.0` enterprise version.

I have defined my custom role `CUSTOM_DELETE` something like below, here `custom:baseAspect` is my custom aspect.

```
<permissionSet type="custom:baseAspect" expose="selected">

        <permissionGroup name="CUSTOM_DELETE_Permission" expose="false" allowFullControl="false"/>

        <permissionGroup name="CUSTOM_DELETE" allowFullControl="false" expose="true">
            <includePermissionGroup type="custom:baseAspect" permissionGroup="CUSTOM_DELETE_Permission" />
            <includePermissionGroup type="sys:base" permissionGroup="Read" />
            <includePermissionGroup type="sys:base" permissionGroup="WriteProperties"/>
            <includePermissionGroup type="sys:base" permissionGroup="Delete"/>
        </permissionGroup>

        <permission name="_CUSTOM_DELETE_Permission" expose="false">
            <grantedToGroup permissionGroup="CUSTOM_DELETE_Permission"/>
        </permission>

    </permissionSet>
```

**Given :**

I am creating any content which is having aspect (`custom:baseAspect`) under public site with assigning permission like this

**`NODE_1 : CUSTOM_DELETE : GROUP_1`**

**Expected Behavior :**

Now if I login with user which under `GROUP_1`, he/she should be able to `Read` content, `Write/Edit Properties` and `Delete`the content.

**Actual Behavior :**

User is able to `Read` content, `Delete` content but not able to `Write/Edit properties`.

Am I doing something wrong?

Regards,
Vishal Z.